# Filter Out Data in Json

Tags: python-3.x

I have the below json file, where i need to filter the City data based on flag value equals to true

```
"attributes": { "State": 
    [ { "type": "sc", "ov": true, "value": "TN" } ], 
    "City": [ { "type": "c", "flag": true, "value": "Chennai" }, 
    { "type": "c", "flag": false, "value": "Coimbatore" } ], 
    }
```

Expecting the output as below

```
State: TN
City: Chennai
```

Comment: Can you accept an answer or comment on why no answer helped

Answer (score 0):

Just load the json file into memory, then use a list comprehension to filter for where the flag is true.

```
import json

with open('yourfile.json', 'r') as citydata:
    cities_dict = json.load(citydata)

true_cities = [city for city in cities_dict['attributes']['City'] if city['flag']]
```

This won't mutate the original data, and will return a separate list of cities where the flag is true. You can just set the same list to the list comprehension's return value to mutate the original data in memory, such as:

```
cities_dict['attributes']['City'] = [city for city in cities_dict['attributes']['City'] if city['flag']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like below to only filter city based on flag is True.

```
import json

data = json.loads(open("/home/imtiaz/tmp/data1.json").read())
data1 = [city for city in data['attributes']['City'] if city['flag'] is True]
data['attributes']['City'] = data1
```